# Dropwizard exception on serializing answer to json

Tags: java, exception, dropwizard

I've configured `ExceptionMapper` for `java.lang.Exception`. So any app exception should be processed by this mapper (I thought).

For some requests I got `500 (Server Error)` response with following content:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /actresses. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><br/>                                                
<br/>
```

I checked logs - empty! I've got following log settings

```
logging:
  level: INFO
```

After changing log level to `DEBUG` dropwizard printed `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` - on serializing answer hibernate throws an exception.

Pls answer following questions:

1. Why does dropwizard not prints this exception with `INFO` level?
2. Why does dropwizard not process this exception by my `ExceptionMapper`?
3. Why does dropwizard return HTML for `Accept: application/json` request?

Comment: A detailed answer for your question 2 is [here](http://thoughtspark.org/2013/02/25/dropwizard-and-jersey-exceptionmappers/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to using DropWizard 0.6 with Java 7. We found the same issue. Upgrading to DW 7, or running with Java 6 should fix it.